# Point domain to custom domain on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to point a domain to my custom domain?

domain1.com --> myapp.com --> myapp.appspot.com

domain2.com --> myapp.com --> myapp.appspot.com

I successfully pointed www.myapp.com to myapp.appspot.com
creating a CNAME and and pointing it to ghs.google.com

Comment: Do you want to redirect or to serve the same pages from `domain1.com` as well?

Comment: You can't serve from bare domains.  You need to either 1. redirect from something else or two masqerade - which is done typically by the dns provider.

Comment: For each domain, what does the user end up seeing as the domain, and where is the request served from? Do both domains see the same thing?

Comment: i want to give my customers the option to 1. use a custom subdomain of myapp.com or use their own domain. but i cant set all the domains on GAE! my idea was to point those customerdomains.com using A NAME to myapp.com (this one is a custom domain on GAE) but is not working

Answer (score 1):

Google will redirect a bare domain for you, it's described at http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2518373.

In this case, mydomain.com would have an A record pointing to a Google IP address, and requests for http://mydomain.com delivered to that IP address would get an HTTP response redirecting the browser to http://www.mydomain.com by Google; www.mydomain.com would have a CNAME DNS entry that points to ghs.google.com; user requests arriving there are routed based on their Host: header to App Engine and then to an instance of your app. The user would see "www.mydomain.com" in their address bar.

I don't know if I fully understand your explanation of the two domains, but if you want users who try to go to http://myotherdomain.com to end up at the app, as well, you should be able to do this with a Google Apps domain alias: add myotherdomain.com as a domain alias for mydomain.com and repeat the steps to get the naked domain redirected and www.myotherdomain.com to go to ghs.google.com, and you can make your app available on www.myotherdomain.com.

Comment: i didn´t know that only domains on google apps can be used with GAE. bad news!

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered today (as of 2014-04-11) a new custom domain settings page is available from Google Developers Console:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project
2. Click on your project
3. On the left click "App Engine"
4. Click "Settings"

There you go! You can configure custom domain without the need of Google App account!